# DB2 - How to Create a TimeStamp from 3 different Fields

Tags: db2

I have to buid a timestamp from 3 different fields.

`Refer_DT` is a TimeStamp that contains the Date.
`Refer_Time` is a TimeStamp that contains The Time.
`REFER_TIME_TYP_CD` is an Integer Field which designates the AM or PM.

I need to build a Timestamp from all three fields.

Thanks in Advance.

```
 Select REFER_ID, REFER_DT, REFER_TIME, REFER_TIME_TYP_CD, VarChar_Format(Refer_Time, 'AM') as Indicator, 
        Case When REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 2858 
                  Then Case When VarChar_Format(REFER_TIME, 'AM') = 'AM' 
                                 Then TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME))
                                 Else TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME - 12 Hours)) 
                       End
             When REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 2859 
                  Then Case When VarChar_Format(REFER_TIME, 'AM') = 'PM' 
                                 Then TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME))
                                 Else TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME + 12 Hours)) 
                       End
        End as "Intake Time"                                                         

From TREFERRAL  
Where REFER_ID = 32351883 
With UR
```

Comment: Could you give some example data - i.e. how does Refer_Time look like and what you expect as result.

Comment: Select Refer_ID, Refer_DT, Refer_Time, REFER_TIME_TYP_CD From TREFERRAL  Where Refer_ID = 32351883;

Comment: 32351883,      1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM,     1/5/2016 12:08:00 PM, 2858

Comment: I have to use the Date portion of Refer_DT and then the Time Portion of Refer_Time while ignoring the PM and AM in that field.  And using the REFER_TIME_TYP_CD field to assign the PM or AM.   2858 is AM and 2859 is PM.

Comment: If you answered the problem yourself you can add that as an answer below as well (and accept it).  Is this table design really mandated by the government?  I find that hard to believe... and it's a terrible design, too (and terribly implemented, if the time value doesn't match the time type-code).  Ideally you should have a single timestamp field, which would be faster to query and prevent issues like this in the first place.

Comment: Yes it is mandated somewhat. The table structure came from Washington DC.   Deloitte was responsible 10 years ago for modifying it to fit the needs of our State.   15 Other States use this model.

Answer (score 0):

So your timestamp field for date has a date with 00:00:00.0000 for the time?

And the timestamp field with the time has a time with 0001-01-01 for a date?

And apparently the TS with the time only has 0-12 hrs...

```
select                                              
  timestamp(date(Refer_DT)                          
            , case                                  
                when REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 1          
                  then time(refer_time) + 12 hours  
                else                                
                   time(refer_time)                 
              end                                   
           )                                        
from mytable
```

Comment: that will not work for this particular record.  The Refer_Time is PM but the REFER_TIME_TYP_CD is AM.  Unfortunately this is by design because of Federal Mandates.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query somewhat:

```
Select REFER_ID, REFER_DT, REFER_TIME, REFER_TIME_TYP_CD, VarChar_Format(Refer_Time, 'AM') as Indicator, 
    Case When REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 2858 And VarChar_Format(REFER_TIME, 'AM') = 'PM' 
              Then TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME - 12 Hours)) 
         When REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 2859 And VarChar_Format(REFER_TIME, 'AM') = 'AM'
              Then TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME + 12 Hours))
              Else TimeStamp(Date(REFER_DT), Time(REFER_TIME)) 
    End as "Intake Time"                                                         

From TREFERRAL  
Where REFER_ID = 32351883 
With UR
```

Note, however, that you've lost whatever sub-second information you previously had (there are ways to recover this, but you haven't specified if you need it).  I'm also curious whether subtracting/adding 12 hours should also subtract/add a day.

Answer (score 0):

And if you do it:

```
select REFER_ID, REFER_DT, REFER_TIME, REFER_TIME_TYP_CD,                                         
TIMESTAMP(                                                     
VARCHAR_FORMAT(REFER_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD-') ||                              
VARCHAR_FORMAT(REFER_TIME, case REFER_TIME_TYP_CD = 2859 then 'HH24' else 'HH12' end || '.MI.SS.NNNNNN')                                  
) "Intake Time" 
From TREFERRAL  
Where REFER_ID = 32351883 
With UR
```